# Do I need to transform time with sin/cos if I'm using decision tree algorithms?

Tags: decision-trees

According to this post, the time on a 24-hour clock should be decomposed into separate periodic components:

https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/encoding-cyclical-features-24hour-time/

before feeding it into an extratrees algorithm, as 24-hour clock numbers are not ordinal (1 comes right after 24...).

My question is, when using decision tree algos, is this necessary?

My lay understanding is that tree algos work in feature space, are non-linear, and perform arbitrary splits, hence this is an unnecessary operation?